# HTACCESS Country block

Tags: .htaccess, geolocation, block, country

I am using this code in my htaccess to block countries. Headers come from cloudflare IP Geolocation. But when i try to enter from this country it loads normally.

```
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry BG BuzzOff=1
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=BuzzOff
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the ip geolocation service.